# Using Redis transaction vs redlock to solve the Lost Update Problem

Tags: node.js, redis, concurrency, redlock

I'm working with a Redis cluster having 2+ nodes. I'm trying to figure out which tool best fits for handling concurrency - transaction or locking. Transactions are [well documented](https://redis.io/topics/transactions), but I didn't find a good best-practice-example on redlock. I also wonder why two tools exist and what's the use case for each.

For simplicity, let's assume I want to do a concurrent increment and there is no INCR command in Redis.

Option 1. **Using Transactions**

If I understand correctly, NodeJS pseudocode would look like this:

```
 transactIncrement = async (key) => {
      await redisClient.watch(key);
      let value = redisClient.get(key);
      value = value + 1;
      const multi = await redisClient.multi();
      try {
        await redisClient.set(key, value, multi);
        await redisClient.exec(multi);
      } catch (e) {
        // most probably error thrown because transaction failed
        // TODO: think if it's a good idea to restart in every case, introducing a potential infinite loop
        // whatever, restart
        await transactIncrement(key); 
      }
    }
```

Bad things I can see above are:

- try-catch block
- possibility to use transactions with multiple keys is limited on redis cluster

Option 2. **Redlock**

**Is it true that trying to lock a resource that's already locked would not cause a failure immediately? So  that redlock tries N times before erroring?**

If true then here's my pseudocode:

```
redlockIncrement = async (key) => {
  await redlock.lock(key, 1);  
  // below this line it's guaranteed that other "threads" are put on hold 
  // and cannot access the key, right? 
  let value = await redisClient.get(key);
  value = value + 1;
  await redisClient.set(key, value);
  await redlock.unlock(key);
}
```

**Summary**

If I got things right then redlock is definitely a more powerful technique. Please correct me if I'm wrong in the above assumptions. It would also be really great if someone provides an example of code solving similar problem because I couldn't find one.

Answer (score 0):

Redlock is [useful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54837601/2395796) when you have a *distributed* set of components that you want to coordinate to create an atomic operation.

You wouldn't use it for operations that affect a single Redis node. That's because Redis already has much simpler and more reliable means of ensuring atomicity for commands that use its single-threaded server: transactions or scripting. (You didn't mention [Lua scripting](https://redis.io/commands/eval), but that's the most powerful way to create custom atomic commands).

Since `INCR` operates on a single key, and therefore on a single node, the best way to implement that would be with a simple Lua script.

Now, if you want to use a sequence of commands that spans multiple nodes neither transactions nor scripting will work. In that case you could use Redlock or a similar distributed lock. However, you would generally try to avoid that in your Redis design. Specifically, you would use [hash tags](https://redis.io/topics/cluster-spec#keys-hash-tags) to force certain keys to reside on the same node:

> Hash tags are a way to ensure that multiple keys are allocated in the same hash slot. This is used in order to implement multi-key operations in Redis Cluster.